# Is it possible to set a different ringtone for each line of a dual SIM iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ringtones

I have an iPhone 11 with a nano-SIM and an e-SIM. I've searched the internet but haven't found anything yet. I didn't see any setting about it, and it would seem normal to me to have two different ringtones - one for work and one for personal calls.

Is it possible to have a different ringtone for the two phone lines that I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently not supported in iOS 13, as an alternative, if you call a contact primarily through a specific SIM, you can set that contact a specific ringtone:

1. Go to contacts
2. Go to the contact
3. Click *Edit*
4. Choose the ring tone

At the moment no alternative solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to have two SIMs active at the same time. [This Apple Support Page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209044) says (with my emphasis):

> With iOS 13 and later, both of your phone numbers can make and receive voice and FaceTime calls and send and receive messages using iMessage, SMS, and MMS.2 **Your iPhone can use one cellular data network at a time**.